# How to install with yum all python packages except broken?

Tags: fedora, software-installation, yum

I want to install all python packages on my Fedora 20 system, and there are broken dependencies. How can I install all except the broken or with errors?

```
]$ sudo yum install *python*
```

.....

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python-qpid_messaging-0.24-3.fc20.x86_64 (fedora)
           Requires: qpid-cpp-client(x86-64) = 0.24
           Available: qpid-cpp-client-0.24-6.fc20.x86_64 (fedora)
               qpid-cpp-client(x86-64) = 0.24-6.fc20
           Installing: qpid-cpp-client-0.26-3.fc20.x86_64 (updates)
               qpid-cpp-client(x86-64) = 0.26-3.fc20
Error: Package: gcc-python2-debug-plugin-0.12-15.fc20.x86_64 (fedora)
           Requires: gcc = 4.8.2-1.fc20
           Installed: gcc-4.8.2-7.fc20.x86_64 (@updates)
               gcc = 4.8.2-7.fc20
           Available: gcc-4.8.2-1.fc20.x86_64 (fedora)
               gcc = 4.8.2-1.fc20
Error: Package: gcc-python3-plugin-0.12-15.fc20.x86_64 (fedora)
           Requires: gcc = 4.8.2-1.fc20
           Installed: gcc-4.8.2-7.fc20.x86_64 (@updates)
               gcc = 4.8.2-7.fc20
           Available: gcc-4.8.2-1.fc20.x86_64 (fedora)
               gcc = 4.8.2-1.fc20
Error: Package: python-neutron-2013.2.3-2.fc20.noarch (updates)
           Requires: python-neutronclient >= 2.3.4
           Available: python-neutronclient-2.3.1-2.fc20.noarch (fedora)
               python-neutronclient = 2.3.1-2.fc20
           Installing: python-neutronclient-2.3.1-3.fc20.noarch (updates)
               python-neutronclient = 2.3.1-3.fc20
Error: Package: gcc-python3-debug-plugin-0.12-15.fc20.x86_64 (fedora)
           Requires: gcc = 4.8.2-1.fc20
           Installed: gcc-4.8.2-7.fc20.x86_64 (@updates)
               gcc = 4.8.2-7.fc20
           Available: gcc-4.8.2-1.fc20.x86_64 (fedora)
               gcc = 4.8.2-1.fc20
Error: Package: gcc-python2-plugin-0.12-15.fc20.x86_64 (fedora)
           Requires: gcc = 4.8.2-1.fc20
           Installed: gcc-4.8.2-7.fc20.x86_64 (@updates)
               gcc = 4.8.2-7.fc20
           Available: gcc-4.8.2-1.fc20.x86_64 (fedora)
               gcc = 4.8.2-1.fc20
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I've tried:

```
]$ sudo yum install *python* --skip-broken
```

But it gives this:

```
Running transaction check
Running transaction test


Transaction check error:
  file /etc/bash_completion.d/django_bash_completion from install of python3-django15-1.5.6-1.fc20.noarch conflicts with file from package python-django-bash-completion-1.6.4-1.fc20.noarch
  file /etc/bash_completion.d/django_bash_completion from install of python-django15-1.5.6-1.fc20.noarch conflicts with file from package python-django-bash-completion-1.6.4-1.fc20.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tests/__init__.py conflicts between attempted installs of python-libturpial-1.7.0-1.fc20.noarch and python-django-federated-login-1.0.0-1.fc20.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tests/__init__.pyc conflicts between attempted installs of python-libturpial-1.7.0-1.fc20.noarch and python-django-federated-login-1.0.0-1.fc20.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tests/__init__.pyo conflicts between attempted installs of python-libturpial-1.7.0-1.fc20.noarch and python-django-federated-login-1.0.0-1.fc20.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/queuelib/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-33.pyc conflicts between attempted installs of python3-queuelib-1.1.1-1.fc20.noarch and python3-python-queuelib-1.0-2.fc20.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/queuelib/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-33.pyo conflicts between attempted installs of python3-queuelib-1.1.1-1.fc20.noarch and python3-python-queuelib-1.0-2.fc20.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/queuelib/__pycache__/pqueue.cpython-33.pyc conflicts between attempted installs of python3-queuelib-1.1.1-1.fc20.noarch and python3-python-queuelib-1.0-2.fc20.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/queuelib/__pycache__/pqueue.cpython-33.pyo conflicts between attempted installs of python3-queuelib-1.1.1-1.fc20.noarch and python3-python-queuelib-1.0-2.fc20.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/queuelib/__pycache__/queue.cpython-33.pyc conflicts between attempted installs of python3-queuelib-1.1.1-1.fc20.noarch and python3-python-queuelib-1.0-2.fc20.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/queuelib/__pycache__/queue.cpython-33.pyo conflicts between attempted installs of python3-queuelib-1.1.1-1.fc20.noarch and python3-python-queuelib-1.0-2.fc20.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/queuelib/pqueue.py conflicts between attempted installs of python3-queuelib-1.1.1-1.fc20.noarch and python3-python-queuelib-1.0-2.fc20.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/queuelib/queue.py conflicts between attempted installs of python3-queuelib-1.1.1-1.fc20.noarch and python3-python-queuelib-1.0-2.fc20.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/queuelib/tests/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-33.pyc conflicts between attempted installs of python3-queuelib-1.1.1-1.fc20.noarch and python3-python-queuelib-1.0-2.fc20.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/queuelib/tests/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-33.pyo conflicts between attempted installs of python3-queuelib-1.1.1-1.fc20.noarch and python3-python-queuelib-1.0-2.fc20.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/queuelib/tests/__pycache__/test_pqueue.cpython-33.pyc conflicts between attempted installs of python3-queuelib-1.1.1-1.fc20.noarch and python3-python-queuelib-1.0-2.fc20.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/queuelib/tests/__pycache__/test_pqueue.cpython-33.pyo conflicts between attempted installs of python3-queuelib-1.1.1-1.fc20.noarch and python3-python-queuelib-1.0-2.fc20.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/queuelib/tests/__pycache__/test_queue.cpython-33.pyc conflicts between attempted installs of python3-queuelib-1.1.1-1.fc20.noarch and python3-python-queuelib-1.0-2.fc20.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/queuelib/tests/__pycache__/test_queue.cpython-33.pyo conflicts between attempted installs of python3-queuelib-1.1.1-1.fc20.noarch and python3-python-queuelib-1.0-2.fc20.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/queuelib/tests/test_pqueue.py conflicts between attempted installs of python3-queuelib-1.1.1-1.fc20.noarch and python3-python-queuelib-1.0-2.fc20.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/queuelib/tests/test_queue.py conflicts between attempted installs of python3-queuelib-1.1.1-1.fc20.noarch and python3-python-queuelib-1.0-2.fc20.noarch

Error Summary
-------------
```

Comment: Have you tried running `yum remove *python*` or `yum clean *python*` or `yum clean all` or any combination?

Comment: @jaredad7 I can try that tomorrow. Don't have Wifi, where I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
~]$ sudo yum install -- '*python*' -python3-queuelib -python-django-federated-login -gcc-python3-plugin -python-qpid_messaging -gcc-python2-plugin -gcc-python3-debug-plugin -python-django* -django* -gcc-python2-debug-plugin -python3-django15-1.5.8-1 python-django-bash-completion* -python-django15*
```

Answer (score 1):

Alas. nothing but rpm can see file conflicts, which is why Fedora policy is that if a package has them it should have an actual conflict too ... but that's one of many packaging things that don't get checked very well.

It looks like there are only a couple of problems though, so you can do:

```
yum install -- '*python*' -python3-queuelib -python-django-federated-login
```

Comment: ]$ sudo yum install -- '*python*' -python3-queuelib -python-django-federated-login -python-django-bash-completion* -gcc-python3-plugin -python-qpid_messaging -gcc-python2-plugin -gcc-python3-debug-plugin -gcc-python2-debug-plugin -python3-django15-1.5.8-1.fc20.noarc   Total size: 1.0 G
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test


Transaction check error:
  file /etc/bash_completion.d/django_bash_completion conflicts between attempted installs of python3-django15-1.5.8-1.fc20.noarch and python-django-bash-completion-1.6.5-1.fc20.noarch

Answer (score 0):

for me:`yum install python3`

you could also `yum search python3` which shows what yum finds, but my simply install python3 worked and installed both python3, python 3.2 with another folder named python 3.2mj as well.